# Why GenericRepository returns a class while I'm using interfaces with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, unit-of-work

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API with C#, .NET Framework 4.5, Entity Framework 6.1.0 **Code First** and `Ninject`.

To do it I'm using **Generic Repository**, **Unit of Work** and **Dependency Injection** patterns (at least, I'm trying to follow them).

I have the following projects:

- MyProduct.Domain
- MyProduct.Interfaces
- MyProduct.WebAPI

On `MyProduct.Interfaces` I have two interfaces:

- IGenericRepository
- IUnitOfWork

On `MyProduct.Domain` I have three folders:

- `Concrete` with the classes: `EFDbContext`, `GenericRepository`
  (implements `IGenericRepository`) and `UnitOfWork` (implements
  `IUnitOfWork`).
- `Configurations` with EF Code First configurations.
- `Entities` with the classes representing database tables.

This is my `IUnitOfWork` interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void SaveChanges();
    IRepository CustomerRepository { get; }
    IRepository ProductRepository { get; }
    IRepository OrderRepository { get; }
}
```

And a controller with constructor injection:

```
private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

public OrderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork )
{
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

And now my problem:

If I get all Customers with `UnitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll();`.

This will return a `IEnumerable<Customer>` and `Customer` its defined in `MyProduct.Domain`. Is that correct?

I'm trying to decouple any Entity Framework reference on `MyProduct.WebApi`, but If I have to add a reference to `Customer` (defined in `MyProduct.Domain`, folder `Entities`) I'm not decoupling anything because I'm referencing `MyProduct.Domain` project.

Maybe I haven't understood anything here because I don't understand why I'm using `IUnitOfWork` interface and then on any action of my controller I have an instance of a class from `MyProducts.Domain`.

Do I need to move my entities to another project called, for instance, `MyProduct.Model`?

Comment: Your unit of work should wrap the calls to your repositories. That's the point of it. The point of UoW is when you have more than 1 repository that need to share a context. @mijal posted a good link that explains why you'd want to use it. If your use case doesn't match, then there's no reason why you can't use the repository directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a choice that you have to made, it doesnt matter move all entities into another project. But in my case I always do it.

If you have doubts, here an idea how to implement the GenericRepository
[How to use generic type with the database Context in EF6 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068981/how-to-use-generic-type-with-the-database-context-in-ef6-code-first/24069692#24069692)

Comment: the DbContext its already a UnitOfWork but using another UnitOfWork as interface or class its usefull only to add your IRepository properties. If want dont use it, in practice I use a combination of my own UnitOfWork, DbContext and invidual IRepositories in my controllers, you have to evaluate each case and choice your best option.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely a good idea to use a Unit of Work and Repository in your application for a multitude of reasons.  However, that doesn't mean you have to create your own Unit of Work and Repository.

Entity Framework's DbContext already *IS* a Unit of Work, and the included DbSet's are already Generic Repositories.  So doing nothing but using EF already satisfies the good practices....

Many people will point to repositories for Unit Testing, and absolutely.  However, as of EF6, you can now do proper mocking of EF contexts for unit testing.  And if you absolutely want to abstract it away, use a concrete repository instead.

The only reason to create your own UnitOfWork class is one of two reasons.  1) You intend to replace your database technology.  or 2) You are using a database technology that doesn't implement a UnitOfWork (ie ADO.NET, or whatever).

As far as #1 goes...

Most people think they might replace their database technology, but that almost never happens.  And if you do, chances are you've probably let so many implementation details leak into your design that it will never be an easy swap out anyways.

for at least 95% of people using custom Generic UnitOfWork/Repositories, it's just useless extra work.  For the 5% that gain benefit, there are probably better ways to achieve the same benefits.

As for #2...

If you're not using an ORM or other technology that already implements UnitOfWork, then you definitely should implement one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bit, what is the answer for my question? Do I need to mover my envites to another Project? I'm using this approach because I want to use TDD and mocking and I want to decouple everything on my solution.

Comment: @VansFannel - Please re-read my third paragraph.  You can test and mock EF 6 without creating generic repositories or uow, and concrete repositories are just as testable.  You can do all of that without all the extra busywork

Comment: Yes, but I'm not asking if I have to use my own UnitOfWork implementation or not.

Comment: @VansFannel - You said "Maybe I haven't understood anything here because I don't understand why I'm using IUnitOfWork", and my point is, if you don't understand why you're doing it.. you probably don't need to be.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't answer my question. My question is : `Do I need to move my entities to another project called, for instance, MyProduct.Model?`

Comment: @VansFannel - How exactly would that prevent you from returning entities from your unit of work?  It wouldn't.  They would still be entities.  If your goal is to decouple completely, for whatever strange reason that might be, then you need to duplicate your entities in each layer and have a translation method to use between them that just copies the data to all your duplicate entities in that other layer.

Comment: Thanks. If I follow your solution, not using `GenericRepository` and `UnitOFWork` because `DBContext` is an `UnitOfWork` and `DBSet` are respositories. How can I use Constructor Injection on my controllers with `DBContext` and `DBSet`?

Comment: @VansFannel - you wouldn't.. you would still put your data layer behind and abstraction of some sort.  A service layer, a concrete repository, command or query objects, etc.. There are many different ways this is done, and you need to figure out what works best for you.